# Refactor: Executing a block of code only if a there is no exception thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a section of code that I would like to run only if the previous block of code doesn't throw an error. I've implemented a solution that seems hacky and I'm sure there is a better way to do it in Ruby.

Here's what I have so far:

```
existing_comments = Comment.all
catch(:creation_failure) do
    begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            results.each do |row|
                Comment.create!(row)
            end
        end
    rescue
        throw(:creation_failure)
    end
    existing_comments.destroy_all
end
```

There's gotta be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to figure out what exactly it is that you are trying to do. As @ehabkost already pointed out, if an exception is raised, the execution is aborted anyway, so there's nothing you need to do. Anything which comes after the code that raised the exception won't be executed anyway, after all that is the *whole point* of exceptions.

Does this do what you want?

```
existing_comments = Comment.all
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    results.each do |row|
      Comment.create!(row)
    end
  end
rescue # You should *never* do this!
else
  existing_comments.destroy_all
end
```

By the way: you should *never*, under no circumstances, just blindly rescue *all* exceptions. You should only ever rescue *exactly* the ones you expect. Do you *really* think it is a good idea to just blindly swallow, say, a `ThreadError` without ever noticing it? There are 39 direct subclasses of `ActiveRecordError` alone, perhaps one of those is more appropriate than just rescuing all exceptions (or at least all `StandardError` exceptions).

Comment: BTW: I'm a big fan of pointfree style, so I'd probably write `results.each(&Comment.method(:create!))` instead of the literal block, but that's just personal preference. I don't like inventing names for variables that I don't need anyway. It elevates those variables to a level of importance they simply don't deserve.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose this refactor:

```
Comment.transaction do
  Comment.destroy_all
  results.each do |row| 
    comment = Comment.new(row)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless comment.save 
  end
end
```

I've moved the comments destroy to the top. While it's not exactly the same (new comments now won't clash against the existing ones), I think this makes more sense.

Note that `throw/catch` -useful as they are in certain scenarios- should not be used in normal coding or you'll end up with inextricable spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Try (I didn't get a chance to test it):

```
existing_comments = Comment.all
rescue Exception => e do 
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    results.each do |row|
      Comment.create!(row)
    end
    #you can log the failure messages, etc… by doing something with e
    existing_comments.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: This would ignore exceptions from the destroy_all method, too. I don't know if the question author wants that.

Comment: Is it valid Ruby to have a rescue block with no begin?

Comment: vrish88- yes, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Transactions - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html - ensure that the block executes as an atomic action. If an exception is raised, the entire transaction is rolledback.

Comment: He's already using a transaction, he want to avoid running additional code after the exception is raised (and the transaction is already aborted).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
existing_comments = Comment.all
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    results.each do |row|
      Comment.create!(row)
    end
  end
  existing_comments.destroy_all
rescue Exception => e
  # do something with the exception??
end
```

In your code you make it difficult (for me) by mixing raising exceptions (handled by `rescue`) and throwing something (handled by `catch`). Most of the times only `raise` is used.

Theory: raise/rescue is used to handle exceptions, throw/catch is used to control flow, and you can throw anything (not just exceptions). Unless really needed, i would avoid catch/throw.

Since when the exception is raised, the flow is interrupted, we can easily profit from that fact and only do the stuff if no exception occurred.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

When I read your question, I thought "wait, this is trivial: just write your code like you always do", e.g.:

```
def my_method
  do_something
  do_something_else
end
```

This way, `do_something_else` will run only if `do_something` doesn't raise an exception. You don't need to do anything special for that.

However, it looks like what you really want to do is to not run `do_something_else` **and** ignore the exception raised by do_something, right?

I have to note that you should be really careful if you are planning to ignore exceptions, but if you really want to do it, an easy way to ignore the exception from a block of code and not run anything else would be to simply return from the method. Like this:

```
def my_method
    existing_comments = Comment.all
    begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            results.each do |row|
                Comment.create!(row)
            end
        end
    rescue
        # just return. ignore any exceptions from the block above
        return
    end
    # this will run only if the above doesn't raise any exception:
    existing_comments.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: See @Jörg W Mittag solution too. Using "else" is simpler than using "return" like I did.